# How to customize typeset code appearance with pythontex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, verbatim, python, pythontex

I use pythontex to execute / display python code in LateX Document (with `pdflatex`) and this work great.
However, when I type

```
\begin{pyverbatim}
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd

p=3.6
up=0.4
n=50
ps = rd.uniform(p-up, p+up, n)
\end{pyverbatim}
```

the python code is correctly highlighted but displayed on the very left of the page. I know I can center it by using a minipage but wrapping pyverbatim with `\begin{center} \begin{minipage}{...} ... \end{minipage}\end{center}` each time is not convenient.

Is there a simple way to wrap pyverbatim into a custom env (I can't manage to do it) or to customize pyverbatim display easily ?

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom environments with the `\VerbatimEnvironment` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\newenvironment{custom}[1]{%
\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{#1}\begin{pyverbatim}}{%
\end{pyverbatim}\end{minipage}\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\begin{custom}{0.5\textwidth}
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd

p=3.6
up=0.4
n=50
ps = rd.uniform(p-up, p+up, n)
\end{custom}
\end{document}
```